# How to complete a vector in an orthogonal basis of $span (v_1, v_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

considering the vector in $R^3$: $$v_1 = (2, -1,  2), v_2 = (1, 0, 1)$$

1. find a vector $u_1$ of norm $1$ in $span (v_1)$
2. find a base of $(spna(v_1, v_2))^\perp$
3. complete $u_1$ in an orthogonal basis of $span (v_1, v_2)$

--

1. $\sqrt{4x^2 +y^2+4z^2} = 1 \iff x = 0, y=1, z = 0$, so $u_1 = (0, 1, 0) $
2. $\begin{bmatrix}
   2 & -1 & 2\\
   1 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & -1 & 0
   \end{bmatrix} \implies B_{(spna(v_1, v_2))^\perp} = (-1, 0, 1)$
3. but for point 2), it is not clear to me how the base is composed. Can I simply take the vector $v_2$ and, therefore, have: $B = \{(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)\}$?

Comment: $(0,1,0)$ is not in $span(v_1)$.

Comment: right, to find $u_1$ I just need to use Gram-Schmidt and orthonormalize $v_1$, so $u_1 = (2/3. -1/3, 2/3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 just take $u_1=\frac{1}{|v_1|}v_1=(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$.
For 3 we have
$$span(v_1,v_2)=\{av_1+bv_2 ; a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}=\{(2a+b,-a,2a+b) ; a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ Find a vector such that
$$
(2a+b,-a,2a+b) \cdot (\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})=0
$$
Notice that $a=4, b=-9$. Then we have that $\{(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}),(-1,-4,-1)\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $span(v_1,v_2)$.